# Selenium: page_source doesn't change after click different tag options

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I want to get the asset of a foundation, this is the main page.

[image]

In this page, I can click 2015,2014...different year tag, and the asset below will be changed by year. But when I try to use beautifulsoup to get page source, page source is always the same, that is to say, the asset is always the number of 2015, never change with the year. I don't how to deal with this problem.

this is my code:

```
def get_asset(year):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get("http://data.foundationcenter.org.cn/financeInfo_1133.html")
  time.sleep(5)
  driver.find_element_by_link_text(year).click()
  html=driver.page_source
  soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
  a = soup.findAll('div',{"id":"content21"})[0]
  driver.close()
  return a
```

Comment: Save the page source to a HTML file and then open it in browser. What you will notice is that all year data will be on the same page and it is all being controlled by JavaScript and CSS. So when you click on the Year link just the page CSS changes are applied and the page source nearly would remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `click()` from `JavaScript`:

```
def get_asset(year):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://data.foundationcenter.org.cn/financeInfo_1133.html")
    time.sleep(5)
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(year)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', link)
```

This seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parser in **soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')** to '**html5lib**'.
It worked for me.